# FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Are someone succed to use the method `FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler` please?

I've already read the following URL's

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler

http://​developers.facebook.com/blog/​post/555

but it still don't work... Someone to help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Here is my source code , when I execute this, nothing gets logged in the console:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body >
    <div id='fb-root'> </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://?connect.facebook.net/en_US/?all.js"> </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      FB.init({
        appId : 'MY_APP_ID',
        oauth : true,
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        oauth : true,
        xfbml: true
      });

      function testUrlHandler(data) {
        if (data.path.indexOf("test1"?) != -1) 
          console.log('test1');
        else if (data.path.indexOf("test2"?) != -1) 
          console.log('test2');
        else 
          console.log('default');
      } 

      FB.Canvas.setUrlHandler(te?stUrlHandler);

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://?connect.facebook.net/en_US/?all.js">` contains an invalid URL .... not sure where the ? marks came from. Maybe this could be the source of your issues??

Comment: thank for your response, but the "?" character only appear on this post (i don't know why) , so this is not the problem....

Comment: There's not enough code for us to see.  I mean you're missing your hyperlinks otherwise the handler would never fire.  Do you have an example url we can play with?

Comment: you can try this http://formation.infostyle.fr

Comment: Better question, do you have a Canvas app that we can look at? That URL does nothing by itself because it's not setup as a Canvas app.

Comment: yes, can you please try this ? http://apps.facebook.com/formationinfostyle/

Answer (score 0):

Per the documentation, the callback is only for links on the parent iframe (Facebook UI)

> Registers the callback for inline processing (i.e. without page
>   reload) of user actions when they click on any link to the current app
>   from Canvas, including:
>
> - All ticker stories
> - Bookmarks
> - Requests from the bookmarks drop-down list
> - Request Notifications stories.

Your links in app wont fire the event.

Comment: So, how can i try to test it ?

Comment: You will have to do something in your application that causes a ticker story.  Go to that ticker story and click it.  :)

Comment: for example a like on the app ?

Comment: No, only the four items from the documentation.

Comment: Ok, then you probably shouldn't need to use that setUrlHandler function then.

Comment: if fact, i need to make this code works :) 

i will try to generate some like or request and see if its appears on tick story, and then test the links, that's right ?
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I've spend 3 hours trying to understand what's wrong with it. Sometimes (really rare occasions ) this thing works just fine, and sometimes FB api just ignores this callback.

Solution - set the callback with delay after init, solution: [How to work with facebook setUrlHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424428/how-to-work-with-facebook-seturlhandler/12404794#12404794)